# How to make changes to a view before the segmented control is clicked?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

I have the following code:

```
 @IBAction func switchViews(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            exclusiveAvatarView.alpha = 1
            normalAvatarView.alpha = 0
        } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            exclusiveAvatarView.alpha = 0
            normalAvatarView.alpha = 1
        }
        
    }
```

Although when I load up the view I want for the first segmented control option, it doesn't trigger until I click the button twice. Basically I have to toggle the segmented control twice for the first option to show the right view. Any ideas for how to fix?

This is the initial view

[image]

[image]

this is the view after I toggle it once

[image]

Comment: @Sweeper no how do I do that?

Comment: Actually, forgot what I said. Are `exclusiveAvatarView` and `normalAvatarView` both initially invisible?

Comment: @Sweeper no they are not

Comment: Assuming the first option of the segmented control is initially selected, isn't the right view being shown already then? What's the problem? Can you show some screenshots showing the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: @Sweeper I just updated my answer to make it more clear

Comment: Is the gray view supposed to be the normal avatars view, and the orange view the exclusive avatars view?

Comment: @Sweeper yes and the exclusive avatars should be orange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216851/discussion-between-sweeper-and-appledeveloper123).

Answer (score 0):

I added this too my code and it did the trick

```
if segmentedControl?.isSelected == false {
            exclusiveAvatarView.alpha = 1
            normalAvatarView.alpha = 0
        }
```